# Different route with different parameters to same method in laravel

Tags: php, laravel-5, routes

I have 2 routes one for get and one for post method.
For get route, i have 2 extra parameters in route, so when post method is called it says error some parameter is missing

Routes.php file,

```
Route::get('/abc/{one}/{two}','MainController@someFunction');
Route::post('/abc','MainController@someFunction');
```

Controller file,

```
someFunction(Request $req, $first,$second){

problem is here when i use post method as there are no parameters 
and this function is expecting $first and $second parameters

}
```

All the code is same if i use two methods. I will get those parameters from url for get and for post i will get them from form. so code is all the same. Its redundant.

Comment: Use two methods in your controller?? Why are you trying to do this - what problem does it solve

Comment: Of course you could use default parameters (`function($first=null, $second=null){if($first){...}`) but, well, yuk. dont do that - create a separate method!

Comment: currently am using 2 methods, all the code is almost same , those two parameters in post method are getting from form and for get method am getting from Url. I feel its redundant

Comment: It is redundent, i'll show you how to refactor it. Ideally post your actual code for a better example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to send post and get both request to same method, if possible try this

```
someFunction(Request $req, $first = null, $second = null){
```

}

Comment: along with @Steve comment if($first){ } completes the answer

Answer (score 2):

Refactor the bulk of your method code into a 3rd private method, and call it from the two 'action' methods

```
class SomeController
{

    private function doStuff($first, $second)
    {
        //lots of
        //code here
        //that you dont want
        //to duplicate
        return $first . $second;
    }

    public function getSomething($first, $second)
    {
        return $this->doStuff($first, $second);

    }

    public function postSomething($request)
    {
        return $this->doStuff($request->first, $request->second);

    }

}
```

If the logic in `doStuff` is quite long, you may want to go a step further and create a separate class to handle that logic, and inject it into the controller:

```
class SomeService
{
    public function doStuff($first, $second)
    {
        return $first . $second;
    }
}

class SomeController
{
    protected $someService;

    public function __construct(SomeService $service)
    {
        $this->someService = $service;
    }


    public function getSomething($first, $second)
    {
        return $this->someService->doStuff($first, $second);

    }

    public function postSomething($request)
    {
        return $this->someService->doStuff($request->first, $request->second);

    }

}
```